# How to customize the schema for an entity in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jsonschema, spring-data-rest

Currently I can get the JSON Schema of a resource by making a GET request to /{resource}/schema (with accept:application/schema+json).

It looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "{java_package}.{resource_class_name}",
  "description" : "rest.description.{resource_class_name}",
  "links" : [ ],
  "properties" : {
    "{property name}" : {
      "type" : "{property_type}",
      "description" : "rest.description.{resource_class_name}.{property_name}",
      "required" : false
    }
  }
}
```

What I cannot figure out is how to change the name, descriptions, or whether the property is required or not. I want to to look like this:

```
{
  "name" : "{resource_name}",
  "description" : "{custom_description}",
  "links" : [ ],
  "properties" : {
    "{property_name}" : {
      "type" : "{property_type}",
      "description" : "{custom_property_description}",
      "required" : {true or false}
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to annotate the entity class this way:

```
@JsonPropertyDescription(value = "{custom_property_description}")
@JsonProperty(required = {true or false})
private {property_type} {property_name};
```

But the end results were the same. Does anyone know how to customize the schema that SDR returns?

Answer (score 0):

With SDR 2.2.X annotate your domain class and fields with `org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.Description` to see "*description*" property populated. "*name*" properties is wired to your domain class name and "*required*" property is set to "false".

***Example***

```
package com.test;

@Description("Application")
public class App {

    @Description("Application Name")
    private String name;
}
```

would yield

```
{
  "name" : "com.test.App",
  "description" : "Application",
  "links" : [ ],
  "properties" : {
    "name" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "description" : "Application Name",
      "required" : false
    }
  }
}
```

Having said that, there is [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-354) to make schema confirm to [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org) which is not yet implemented.

Comment: Is there a way to change the top level name? I don't want to show the package.

Comment: Do I have to manually annotate every property? Can I just not show descriptions at all?

Comment: It's optional. Non annotated fields will have empty description

Comment: Currently without the annotation they have the full path including the package and class name

Comment: Looks like the functionality has changed then. Note I didn't verify this personally